# Cannot get right output while doing prolog implementation of getting all unique vertices from the graph

Tags: prolog

I want to write predicate to get all unique vertices of the given graph.
The predicate `allvert(G, L)` must succeed if the argument G is the form `[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 4, 1 ] ] )` and L is the list of all unique vertices of this graph, that is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. Here is my attempt to solve this problem, and actually if I look at the trace my second argument it correct until some point (almost the end of trace), where prolog goes from bot to up, and eventually it returns empty list:

```
allvertices([], K).

allvertices([[X,Y]|R], L) :-
                L = [],
                setinsertion(X,L,M),
                setinsertion(Y,M,K),
                allvertices(R,K).
allvertices([[X,Y]|R],L) :- 
                L \= [],
                setinsertion(X,L,M),
                setinsertion(Y,M,K),
                allvertices(R,[]).
```

Any help will be appreciated.

UPD: setinsertion defined as:

```
setinsertion(X,S1,S1):- member(X,S1),!.
setinsertion(X,S1,[X|T]):-
                        S1 = T,
                        notcontains(X, T).
```

Comment: `allvertices([], K).` says that an empty graph can have anything I want for vertices. Is that what you intend? What should `K` be here?

Comment: What is `setinsertion/3` and how is it defined?

Comment: You really need to study something about Prolog... or take this 'solution' as is: `allvert(G, L):-flatten(G,F),sort(F,L).`

Comment: @CapelliC actually I already have solution using flatten, but the problem is that I cannot use build in methods in prolog

Comment: @lurker I've updated the questoin